# Different accidental notations for the same key within the same measure

Tags: notation, accidentals

Mozart sonata K545, first movement, measure 32, the same key appearing twice, as Db and C#, respectively (see circles in image). Is it because this way it looks more uniform like in the previous measure? Is it also why the accidentals in the bass scales in these two measures are noted the way they appear? Is such consideration a rule to follow or just a preference by the composer?

[image]

Comment: Is the top line relevant? If so, what no. bar?

Comment: @Tim it's the previous one, bar 31.

Comment: I show the previous measure to show the pattern/shape which I thought was the reason to notate that way.

Comment: @seamurmurs By showing the previous bar you confirmed it should be a C#. the first and fourth notes of the RH 16th run are spelled the same in the previous bar. I agree with the answers, C# both times, it’s part of a D harmonic minor scale over the V resolving to Dm in the following bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That D♭ is...odd. Typically the accidentals will be spelled following a few different conventions:

1. Following the key of the current section (e.g., if you're in B♭, the notation will in most cases prefer B♭ to A♯).
2. Following the direction of resolution (e.g., if something moves up by half step to D, it's easier to spell it as C♯–D than as D♭–D♮).

Following an A-major scale in the left hand and an implied D-minor scale in the right, this note should certainly be spelled as C♯.

The *Neue Mozart Ausgabe*, by the way, uses a C♯ at this location; you can access the score (but it's not public domain in the US) [here](https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/425737/hfbu). I've only found this erroneous D♭ in the public transcription available [here](https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/94587/hfbu).

Comment: Somehow, 'conventions' seems far more fitting that 'rules'!

Comment: @Richard  ^That's exactly where I got my copy, from IMSLP.

Comment: So is it still possible in some scenario that the same key within the same bar is notated differently?

Comment: @seamurmurs That may occasionally happen in more chromatic works. Let's say Robert Schumann is in A-flat major and he goes to bVI. He may temporarily spell this as F-flat major before changing it to E major. But in most cases, it will be spelled the same.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Urtext at IMSLP, the example you give is notated wrong.

[image]

Comment: I saw another version (free-scores) has that same as your Urtext, too. But the same question applies, because they are still different, just in reverse. Is it because the first C in this measure is noted as C#?

Comment: What is that question? How to choose accidentals? Like when to use `Db` or `C#`?

Comment: @seamurmurs I strongly believe that the issue is not that important, and it's just an error of the copyist, probably due to some copy/past gone wrong, as it clearly *is* a C# and there's absolutely no reason to use a Db there.

Comment: Question is why the same key is notated differently within the same bar.

Comment: @seamurmurs, give bar, beat, & note number for what two notes you mean. Your original question circled: bar 32, beat 3, 2nd 16th note, and bar 32, beat 4, 1st 16th. In the urtext they are _both_ `C#`.

Comment: @MIchaelCurtis I got it, sorry.

Comment: BTW, bar 32 is very interesting for other reasons. Notice how in bar 32, beat 2 has a `G#` in the bass, and beat 4 has `G` natural in the treble. Also, bar 32, beat 2 has `F#`, then bar 33, beat 1, has `F` natural. From the end of bar 31 to the beginning of 33 the basic harmony is `Dm: ... iv | V V7 |  i ... ` but there are several interesting _cross relationships_ in the various `F`'s and `G`'s.

Comment: Thanks for the observations. This is very helpful as I'm a beginner learning on my own.